# System.IndexOutOfRangeException - Indice Fuera de los límites de la matriz en VB.NET

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, vb

Estoy haciendo un trabajo práctico sobre métodos de ordenamiento y en un método de seleccion directa me aparece este error, pero no logro ver qué está mal. Comparé con uno que si funciona y en teoría es igual al mio. El error me lo marca en el IF.

```
    Dim candidato As Long
    Dim menor As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim aux As Long
    Dim tInicio As Long, tFin As Long

    v = o.Clone
    Dim Limite = v.GetUpperBound(0)
    tInicio = DateTime.Now.Ticks

    candidato = 0
    While candidato < Limite
        cCondicionales += 1
        menor = candidato
        cAsignaciones += 1
        i = candidato + 1
        While i <= Limite
            cCondicionales += 1
            **If v(i) < v(menor) Then**
                cAsignaciones += 1
                menor = -1
            End If
            i += 1
        End While
        cAsignaciones += 3
        aux = v(candidato)
        v(candidato) = v(menor)
        v(menor) = aux
        candidato += 1
    End While
    tFin = DateTime.Now.Ticks
    TiempoTranscurrido = (tFin - tInicio) / 10000000
```

Comment: te recomiendo editar tu pregunta con lo que me acabas de mencionar y-o agregar un comentario al codigo de donde esta el error, ten en cuenta que si tu pregunta no es clara o difilcuta responderla, la mayoria de usuarios ni siquiera se molestaran en leer la seccion de comentarios y por ende no recibiras ayuda.

Comment: Dónde define o?

Answer (score 0):

Como indicas, el error está en esta parte del código:

```
    While i <= Limite
        cCondicionales += 1
        If v(i) < v(menor) Then
            cAsignaciones += 1
            menor = -1
        End If
        i += 1
    End While
```

Vamos a ver qué ocurre en ejecución paso a paso:

1. Mientras el valor de `i` sea menor que el mayor indice

   1. Realiza operaciones
   2. Si `v(i)` es menor que `v(menor)` (el valor inicial de `menor` es 0) entonces

      - Realiza operaciones
      - Pon el valor -1 en `menor`
   3. Incrementa `i`

El programa entra en el bucle `while` (1), realiza las operaciones (1.1) y llega al condicional de 1.2. Si es falso, salta a 1.3 y vuelve al principio del bucle. ¿Pero qué pasa si es verdadero? Si es verdadero, se realizan algunas operaciones y se poner el valor de `menor` a -1. Y ahí es donde está el problema.

En la siguiente iteración del bucle `while` se va a intentar acceder a `v(i)` (sin problemas) y a `v(menor)`. ¡Pero **`menor` es -1 que está fuera del rango de índices válidos**! Por eso el programa lanza la excepción y termina con error.

La solución es que **`menor` no debe ponerse a -1, debe ponerse a `i`** (que será el índice del menor elemento en el array. Con eso, obtendrás el valor correcto:

```
    While i <= Limite
        cCondicionales += 1
        If v(i) < v(menor) Then
            cAsignaciones += 1
            menor = i
        End If
        i += 1
    End While
```